# IDE for intepreting and compiling multiple languages: Fortran, C, Python, Octave, R...

Tags: linux, ide, scientific-computing, fortran

I am working with Linux systems.

I am looking for a [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) where I can write up and compile FORTRAN codes.

However, currently I am also coding in bash, Octave, Python and R --- for these I already have separated IDE's. 
In the near future I might get started with C and C++.

So, if it exists, I would like to use an IDE that can handle in-one these many programming languages, or just most of them.
This IDE should be freeware.

Which IDE's have this capability to host multiple languages?

Answer (score 1):

EMACS or XEMACS, *and numerous other versions* can act as an editor and IDE for multiple languages by using the packages that are available.

A recommended package repository is [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/), *but there are others*, there you will find 3,543 Packages including ones for:

- FORTRAN
- bash
- C/C++/C#
- Octave
- Python
- R
- Just about everything.

EMACS is free, open source and available for most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs with `lsp-mode` (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) and `flycheck` (https://www.flycheck.org) will be a good choice to target multiple languages simultaneously. 
According to lsp-mode supported languages table: fortran, c++, python, R and Julia are already supported